# can't import components inside of my router.js (VueJS)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, components, vuejs3, vue-router

I want to work with `vue-router`, but I'm not able to import my `components` into my `router.js`.

I also get following warning: `[Vue Router warn]: No match found for location with path "/"`

I actually don't know what I'm doing wrong.. hopefully someone can help me out.

***MAIN.JS***

```
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router/router.js';

import '@popperjs/core'
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
import 'bootstrap-icons/font/bootstrap-icons.css'
import store from './store/store.ts'

createApp(App).use(store).use(router).mount('#app')
```

***ROUTER.JS***

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory  } from 'vue-router'

//I've tried following to import but non of these are working out for me
//import test from "../components/test.vue";
//const test= () => import("../components/test.vue");

export default createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
    routes: [
      {
        path: "/test",
        name: "TEST",
        component: () => import("../components/test.vue")
      }
    ]
  });
```

***MY STRUCTURE***

```
- src
    - assets
    - store
    - components
        - test.vue
    - router
        - router.js
    - App.vue
    - main.js
```

afterwards I want to open the component in a new window like this:

```
methods: {
  after_button_click() {
    let route = this.$router.resolve({ name: "TEST" });
    window.open(route.href, "_blank");
  },
}
```

**INFO**: I don't get any errors but it's not working.

Comment: Is `process.env.BASE_URL` defined? how are you starting the app? also, try to see if importing `test.vue` at the top and then using it directly without a function helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar setup in my application and this works for me:

**main.js**

```
import { createApp } from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
```

**index.js (inside './router'**

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import TestComponent from '../components/TestComponent.vue'

const routes = [
  {
    path: '/test',
    name: 'test',
    component: TestComponent

  }]
const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory("/"),
  routes
})

export default router
```

This should give you a working router when you browse to /test.

Hope this helps!